# Updateing value from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm updating value's first time. I have two tables. One table has old values, It is main table and it should be updated. In second table I have new values. On both tables I have same User_ID.

database name is 'intranet'

First Table's name is 'wp_bp_xprofile_data'

```
id     field_id   user_id   value           last_updated
59430   13        4442      598902299       22-Mar-19 20:19:54
59443   13        4443      599847428       22-Mar-19 20:19:54
59456   13        4444      598644555       22-Mar-19 20:19:54
```

Second Table's name is 'idgeorge'

```
user_id z9
4444    598644555
4443    599847428
4442    598902299
```

this is example for three users, there are thousands more...

I searched some examples and wrote down code, but it does not works. Here is my code.

```
UPDATE wp_bp_xprofile_data
SET wp_bp_xprofile_data.value = idgeorge.z9 
WHERE idgeorge.user_id = wp_bp_xprofile_data.user_id 
and 
wp_bp_xprofile_data.field_id=13 
FROM intranet.idgeorge
```

It gives error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM 'intranet.idgeorge'' at line 11
```

but I cant figure out what is missing or what's wrong.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: A good tip is to start with a SELECT. It's often fairly straightforward to turn a SELECT into an UPDATE.

Comment: And here's an example of a query with valid syntax. There's not enough info to know whether it's the one your looking for... `UPDATE wp_bp_xprofile_data x
  JOIN idgeorge y
    ON y.user_id = x.user_id 
   SET x.value = y.z9 
 WHERE x.field_id = 13`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for an `update`/`join`.  In MySQL this looks like:

```
UPDATE wp_bp_xprofile_data pd join
       intranet.idgeorge i
       USING (user_id)
    SET pd.value = i.z9 
    WHERE pd.field_id = 13 ;
```

MySQL does not support a `FROM` clause in an `UPDATE`.  All databases that do follow the normal ordering of clauses, where the `WHERE` needs to follow the `FROM`.